# asp.net login controls with customize logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

Asp.net C# (visual studio 2010) offers built-in mechanism of Membership, authentication and aurhtorization. What if someone has created its own databases with different structre and different registration information? I ma totally new to this stuff. I actually want these services for my web project which has its own database different from the default aspnetdatabase. I tried to find out the source code of default asp.net loging controls to edit for my own needs, but it didn't show the source code where it could be modified for my own database. Can anyone point out the other way around if we want these services with customize logic? Any link or other resource will be a valueable grant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create own `MembershipProvider`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx

How to: Implement a Custom Membership User

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hi, i am checking it. I will give response afther checking it. Thank you

Comment: Or use SimpleMembership - it's usually, erm, simpler - http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx